# How to read required key, values from json response and store it in json format using robot framework?

Tags: json, python-3.x, list, dictionary, robotframework

I am trying to read the required key and values from JSON Response and store it in JSON file.

I have a sample simplified json format as below:

```
 ${API_Output}= {
"data": {
"resources": {
"edges": [
{
"node": {
    "tags": [],
   }
},
{          
  "node": {
   "tags": [
      {
        "name": "app",
        "value": "e2e"
      },
      {
        "name": "Cost",
         "value": "qwerty"
      }
  }
},
{          
  "node": {
   "tags": [
      {
        "name": "app",
        "value": "e2e"
      },
      {
        "name": "Cost",
         "value": "qwerty"
      },
        {
        "name": "test",
         "value": "qwerty"
      }
  }
}
]
}
}
}
```

Here, I am reading the tags name and value which are present. I have used the dictionary key "set to dictionary"  but that prints only the last response of the tags.

I want to know how to append or add the data into the dictionary and store it in JSON format.

Robot code I have used:

```
 ${dict1}=        Set Variable  ${API_Output}
 ${cnt}=     get length     ${dict1['data']['resources']['edges']}
 ${edge}=   set variable      ${dict1['data']['resources']['edges']}

 run keyword if   ${cnt}==0     set test message    The resources count is 
  Zero(0)
  log to console  ${cnt}-count

: FOR    ${item}    IN RANGE   0    ${cnt}
 \    ${readName}=    Set Variable     ${edge[${item}]['node'] 
       ['configuration']}
 \    ${readvalue2}=    Set Variable     ${edge[${item}]['node']['tags']}
  \    ${tag_Count}=    get length     ${edge[${item}]['node']['tags']}
 \    ${tag_variable}=   set variable   ${edge[${item}]['node']['tags']}
 \    forkeyword       ${tag_Count}   ${tag_variable}    ${readName}

 ${req_json}    Json.Dumps    ${dict}
 Create File  results.json  ${req_json}


forkeyword
[Arguments]       ${tag_Count}      ${tag_variable}     ${readName}
@{z}=   create list
 : FOR    ${item}    IN RANGE   0    ${tag_Count}
     \   ${resourceName}=    run keyword if     ${tag_Count} > 0   set 
     variable    ${readName['name']}
     \   log to console  ${resourceName}-forloop
     \   ${readkey}=     set variable   ${tag_variable[${item}]['name']}
     \   ${readvalue}=     set variable   ${tag_variable[${item}]['value']}
     \   set to dictionary     ${dict}     resourceName   ${resourceName}
     \   set to dictionary  ${dict}    ${readkey}     ${readvalue}
 set suite variable ${dict}
```

Output is in Values.json file I get only last tags values.

```
        {
        "name": "app",
        "value": "e2e"
      },
      {
        "name": "Cost",
         "value": "qwerty"
      },
        {
        "name": "test",
         "value": "qwerty"
      }
```

But, I need all the tags values of both tags. Can anyone guide me on how can I use a dictionary or list keywords? to store all tags' response in the file.
I am newbie to robot framework so I apologies if I made any mistake.

Comment: Your code does not work for me

Comment: Did not work for me either, plus that the JSON is invalid. Also, with the current `set to dictionary  ${dict}    ${readkey}     ${readvalue}` you cannot get the same output, but `"anotherName":"val123"` instead, meaning that the key-value pair is values of both keys (name, value).

Comment: And yes, that should be possible inn RF, you probably have to put them in a list to avoid that problem where you have only one set of data, which get updated through the loop instead of appending.

Comment: Your json file output doesn't correspond to the data in your quesyion; in it, the list your iterating over has 2 elements, but you're looping three times, getting out of it. That should raise an index out of range exception, on the third. Also, the sample input json response is not a list of such elements - the "tags" are keys in dictionaries in a list. So something doesn't add up, it's either different input, or you're doing ops not shown. Please correct the examples.

Comment: `set variable   ${['id']['tags']}` there are three `{['id']['tags']`, which one are you storing? `IN RANGE   0    3` the largest has 2 elements, how come you're iterating over 3?

Comment: @TodorMinakov, added the full json and changed the code. can you please verify now!

Comment: @Robotframework, Can anyone guide me on the code part how to store all keys and values by appending them using python or robot code