# Is there a way to store only required keys and values from json response in to file using robot framework?

Tags: python, python-3.x, robotframework

I want to read muliptle keys and values from json response and store it in another file.

I have tried using robot framework.

```
 name:1
 name:2  
 name: 3     
 : FOR    ${item}    IN RANGE   0    5
  \   ${readname}=     set variable   [${item}]['name']
  append to list ${z}  ${readname}

  writeJson   ${z}

 def writeJson(data):
    with open("data_file.json", "w") as write_file:
       json.dump(data, write_file)
```

I expected all values but only last value is stored.

Comment: This should give you a good start: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51878998/5496433

Comment: @BallpointBen, What keyword can i use? from that link I searched not sure what to use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you are doing it in the sample code, the `Append To List` is not inside the loop, but called only once - with the last value of `${z}`. 
Try putting it inside it, thus you'll be appending on each iteration of the loop, e.g. each of the values:

```
:FOR    ${item}    IN RANGE   0    5
  \   ${readname}=     set variable   [${item}]['name']
  \   Append To List ${z}  ${readname}
```

Comment: Can i use set to dictionary instead. I need to get the name in json format and store in a file. But if i use that set dictionary it is appending and printing only last values

Comment: You can, if the data structure you're storing into is a dictionary, and you have different key names for each element - if you use one and the same, each call will overwrite its value.

Comment: ,can you guide me on this link for dictionary code,
https://stackoverflow.com/q/58797352/11867978